# Defining the Content-Language header in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

According to the W3C, a viable and often preferred way to [communicate the language of the intended audience](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/#ri20040808.101452727) is by providinga `Content-Language` header. Relevant part:

> Metadata about the language of the intended audience is usually best declared outside the document in the HTTP Content-Language header.

How can I send such a header with Rails?

Comment: You can use following code in your controller: ``response.headers["Content-Language"] = 'en'``. Also there is new default headers setting in Rails 4:  
http://chriszetter.com/blog/2013/10/04/setting-headers-in-rails-4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd probably be preferred that you use the I18n framework for this:

```
response.headers["Content-Language"] = I18n.locale.to_s
```

Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Indeed I was planning to use the  I18n framework. However, I fail to see where or how I can send such headers from. Is `response` available in the Controller?

Comment: @berkes See here: "In every controller there are two accessor methods pointing to the request and the response objects associated with the request cycle that is currently in execution.": http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object

Comment: In that case: should it not be `response.headers`? (plural)

Comment: is you would typically use symbols for `I18n.locale` it should be `response.headers["Content-Language"] = I18n.locale.to_s`

Answer (score 7):

Just going one step past markshiz's excellent answer, try adding this to app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
after_action :set_response_language_header
def set_response_language_header
    response.headers["Content-Language"] = I18n.locale.to_s
end
```

And you'll never have to worry about it again.